# Converting to polar double integral with a specific order of integration

Tags: multiple-integral

We are asked to write down the integral
$$I=\int_0^1 \int_x^{x\sqrt3}f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dydx$$
in a polar form first with respect to $\theta$ and then with respect to $r$.

I have recognised that $0<r<2$ and $r=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$ but I am finding it difficult to find bounds for $\theta$ as a function of $r$.

Answer (score 1):

The boundaries are the the three lines of the triangle, which transform in polar to

$$\begin{cases}y = x \\ y = \sqrt{3}x \\ x = 1\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}\theta = \frac{\pi}{4} \\ \theta = \frac{\pi}{3} \\ r = \sec\theta\end{cases}$$

giving us the integral

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_0^{\sec\theta}f(r)\:r\:dr\:d\theta$$

To swap the integral, we can either look at the Cartesian graph of the lines

[image]

where $\theta$ integrals move along concentric circles, or in an $r\theta$ plane

[image]

where $\theta$ integrals move in horizontal lines parallel to the $\theta$ axis. In both cases, we can see that region is split in two by the red line, which represents the circle $r^2=2$. This gives us the two integrals

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}f(r)\:r\:d\theta\:dr + \int_{\sqrt{2}}^2\int_{\sec^{-1}(r)}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}f(r)\:r\:d\theta\:dr$$

$$ = \int_0^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\pi r}{12}f(r)\:dr + \int_{\sqrt{2}}^2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\right)rf(r)\:dr$$

Comment: Ok thank you, this make a lot of sense. I didn't recognise that this had to be split into two integrals.

Answer (score 0):

To express the integral $I$ in polar form, we can make the substitution $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$. This gives us:

$$I = \int_0^1 \int_x^{x\sqrt{3}} f(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) \frac{r}{\cos\theta}\sin\theta drd\theta$$

To find the bounds for $\theta$, we need to consider the region of integration in the $xy$-plane. This region is a triangle with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,\sqrt{3})$. We can see that the $x$-coordinate varies from 0 to 1 and the $y$-coordinate varies from 0 to $x\sqrt{3}$, as indicated in the integral.

In polar coordinates, the line $y = 0$ corresponds to the angle $\theta = 0$ and the line $y = x\sqrt{3}$ corresponds to the angle $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$. Therefore, the bounds for $\theta$ are $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Substituting these bounds into the integral, we get:

$$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_0^{\frac{1}{\cos\theta}} f(r) r\sin\theta drd\theta$$

This is the integral $I$ expressed in polar form with respect to $\theta$. To express the integral in polar form with respect to $r$, we can simply switch the order of integration:

$$I = \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} f(r) r\sin\theta d\theta dr + \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^2 \int_0^{\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{r}\right)} f(r) r\sin\theta d\theta dr$$

This is the integral $I$ expressed in polar form with respect to $r$.

Comment: You were right about the split into two integrals, however your bounds for $r$ first are incorrect

Comment: The region is $(0,0), (1,1), (1,\sqrt3)$ no? Because you are bounded below by $y=x$. Also, how does the substitution of $x,y$ yield your initial integral?

Comment: @zakzaki really out of the four bounds in the $r$ first integral, only the lower angular one is incorrect as it should be the line $y=x$. Is that the bound you were asking about because the answerer did the other things up to this point correctly.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes his lower bound should be $\frac{\pi}{4}$ shouldnt it?

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the region of integration is the triangular region bounded by the points $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(1,\sqrt{3})$. These points correspond to the vertices of the triangle, and the line $y=x$ is one of the sides of the triangle.

To perform the substitution of variables to express the integral in polar coordinates, we can start by expressing the points $(1,1)$, $(1,\sqrt{3})$, and $(0,0)$ in polar coordinates. For example, the point $(1,1)$ corresponds to the point $(r,\theta)=(1,\frac{\pi}{4})$ in polar coordinates.

Comment: Similarly, the point $(1,\sqrt{3})$ corresponds to the point $(r,\theta)=(1,\frac{\pi}{3})$, and the point $(0,0)$ corresponds to the point $(r,\theta)=(0,0)$.

Using these coordinates, we can express the bounds of the integral in polar coordinates. The bounds for the integral with respect to $r$ are easy to find because they correspond to the minimum and maximum values of the radius $r$. In this case, the minimum value of $r$ is 0, and the maximum value of $r$ is 1.

Comment: To find the bounds for the integral with respect to $\theta$, we need to consider the angles formed by the line $y=x$ and the two sides of the triangle that are not parallel to $y=x$. These angles can be found by drawing a line segment from the origin to each of the points $(1,1)$ and $(1,\sqrt{3})$, and measuring the angle between this line segment and the line $y=x$.

Using these angles, we can express the bounds of the integral with respect to $\theta$. In this case, the minimum value of $\theta$ is 0, and the maximum value of $\theta$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Using these bounds, we can express the integral in polar coordinates as $$\int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} f(\sqrt{r^2 + r^2 \sin^2 \theta}) r , d\theta dr$$

To see how this expression for the integral in polar coordinates corresponds to the original expression for the integral in Cartesian coordinates, we can substitute the expression for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$:

$$x = r \cos \theta$$
$$y = r \sin \theta$$

Substituting these expressions into the original integral, we get

$$\int_0^1 \int_x^{x\sqrt3}f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dydx$$

Comment: This is the same as the expression for the integral in polar coordinates that we found earlier.

Comment: But is it unclear to me how you have switched from $drd\theta$ to $d\theta dr$

Comment: @MarcoDj01 your error in logic is assuming that $(0,0)$ in $xy$ is $(0,0)$ in polar. That doesn't make any sense. The origin can take on any $\theta$ value in polar coordinates.